# iconv conversion to UTF-8 results in non displayable characters

Tags: html, c, encoding, utf-8, iconv

I am using `iconv.h` in C to convert encoding from `ISO-8859-*` to `UTF-8`. I need the incoming stream to be displayed in the browser. But the result after conversion is not getting displayed in chrome. In other browsers, it is working correctly.
A sample of string is given below

```
char *str = "\x05\x86\x53";
char dest_str[100];
char *out = dest_str;
size_t inbytes = strlen(str);
size_t outbytes = sizeof dest_str;
printf("Before Conversion: %2x %2x %2x\n",str[0],str[1],str[2]);
iconv_t conv = iconv_open("UTF-8//TRANSLIT", "ISO-8859-9");

if (conv == (iconv_t)-1) {
    perror("iconv_open");
    return 1;
}

if (iconv(conv, &str, &inbytes, &out, &outbytes) == (size_t)-1) {
    perror("iconv");
    return 1;
}

dest_str[sizeof dest_str - outbytes] = 0;
printf("After Conversion: %2x %2x %2x\n",dest_str[0],dest_str[1],dest_str[2]);
puts(dest_str);
```

**Output**: Before Conversion:  5 ffffff86 53

**After Conversion**:  5 ffffffc2 ffffff86

Is the conversion taking place correctly? How to solve this problem of non-displayable characters in chrome?

Comment: What are you expecting to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the conversion is correct. The only problem is theat the UTF-8 string has four bytes but you only print the first three.

Obviously, 05 is a non printing character. It's meaning doesn't make sense in abrowser context. (Why are you sending it?) It could be that Chrome refuses to print anything with control codes in it.

The conversion of 0x86 to 0xC2 0x86 is correct. However, it is possible that the font you are using doesn't have a glyph for it. On my Mac, this appears to be the case.

**EDIT**

Having checked out [ISO-8859-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9) it turns out that the sequence you are translating contains one ASCII control  code (0x05), one undefined character (0x86) and one ASCII printable character (0x53 or S). The conversion to UTF-8 leaves the ASCII characters (printable or not) untouched but converts the non ASCII character correctly into a UTF-8 two byte sequence. Two out of three of your characters don't make sense when rendered as text and Chrome is clearly refusing to do this.

Comment: How does the conversion take place? I wish to remove the control characters before sending data to the browser. Thus would I have to remove two bytes of data from the string instead of one i.e. 0xC2 0x86?

Comment: No `C2 86` is not a control character, it is a multibyte UTF-8 character. The `05` is a control character and should be removed.

Comment: Characters from 0 -31 and 127 tp 159 falls under the category of control characters [link](https://www.obliquity.com/computer/html/unicode0000.html) U+0086 is in fact stated as selected area